# What are "t" and "v" in web3.utils.soliditySha3()?

Tags: solidity, web3js, signature, sha3, message

I am going through some code and I have seen:

```
const message = Web3.utils.soliditySha3(
      {t: 'address', v: recipient.address},
      {t: 'uint256', v: recipient.totalAllocation.toString()}
    ).toString('hex');
// see t and v above 
const web3 = new Web3('');
const { signature } = web3.eth.accounts.sign(
    message, 
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
);
```

What are "t" and "v" in web3.utils.soliditySha3()? What do they do? What do they mean?

I have gone through the [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3) but they do not say much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` and `v` are aliases for `type` and `value`, as mentioned in the docs you linked:

> an object with {type: 'uint', value: '123456'} or {t: 'bytes', v: '0xfff456'}

The type is used for ABI encoding the value, before hashing it.

Comment:  Thanks. I do not know why I didn’t see that. Thank you for still answering.